# Creating XML-file with PHP dynamically (general strategy)

Tags: php, xml, xslt, rss, feed

The core of my website is an XML-file master.xml. I am trying to create feeds out of it, a classic rss-feed and a podcast-feed, which means XML to XML.

The first method I tried was creating a real XML-file with PHP's DomDocument, but I ran into fundamental problems. Even if it works correctly, it still creates a file which is not the file that is being requested.

Now I have changed podcast.xml into podcast.php and echo the XML-declaration and the XML-markup with a loop of the items. Readers like iTunes work perfectly with that. But the browsers can't be fooled for real.

1. Chrome puts the content into a pseudo-HTML-file and displays plain text, ignoring the xsl-stylesheet. Nonetheless it displays nothing but XML in the codeview.
2. Firefox displays it like a real XML-file, but in the codeview it shows the closing  reddishly as if the was a markup error (which is not the case).

That makes me (as a private person with ambition) wonder how professionals deal with the desire to create feeds dynamically. Surely, I am not the first person who is trying this.

Comment: DOM is a valid and good way (another would be XMLWriter). You should describe the problem you have with DOM. The XML view in chrome is broken, it displays as HTML even if it is valid XML with the right content type.

Comment: The DOM method results in a XMP-make-up.
I have experienced that Chrome behaves oddly, but it is a popular browser and I want people to be able to look at the feed as a styled page (with xsl and css).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small open source library for this.

You can download and learn how to use it [here](https://github.com/read2me-online/itunes-podcast-feed-php).

Here's an example:

```
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Channel;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\FeedGenerator;
use iTunesPodcastFeed\Item;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// SETUP CHANNEL
$title = 'Read2Me Daily Curated Articles';
$link = 'https://read2me.online';
$author = 'NYTimes and Medium';
$email = 'hello@read2me.online';
$image = 'https://d22fip447qchhd.cloudfront.net/api/widget/static/images/default-thumbnail.png';
$explicit = false;
$categories = [
    'News',
    'Technology',
    'Culture',
    'Entrepreneurship',
    'Productivity'
];
$description = 'Daily curated articles from New York Times and Medium';
$lang = 'en';
$copyright = 'The New York Times Company and The Medium Company';
$ttl = 43200; // 12 hours in seconds

$channel = new Channel(
    $title, $link, $author, $email,
    $image, $explicit, $categories,
    $description, $lang, $copyright, $ttl
);

// SETUP EPISODE
$title = "Trump Says Disclosure of Mueller Questions in Russia Probe Is ‘Disgraceful’";
$fileUrl = 'https://s3.read2me.online/audio/www-nytimes-com-2018-05-01-us-politics-trump-mueller-russia-questions-html-7e9601.mp3';
$duration = '2:18';
$description = 'WASHINGTON — President Trump on Tuesday said it was “disgraceful” that questions the special counsel would like to ask him were publicly disclosed, and he incorrectly noted that there were no questions about collusion. The president also said collusion was a “phony” crime.';
$date = 1525177808;
$filesize = 828387;
$mime = 'audio/mpeg';

$item = new Item(
    $title, $fileUrl, $duration,
    $description, $date, $filesize, $mime
);
$item2 = clone $item; // just to give you an idea of how it works

// SETUP FEED
$feed = new FeedGenerator($channel, ...[$item, $item2]);

// OUTPUT XML
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

print $feed->getXml();
```